# How do I pan the view in Blender?

Tags: 3d-view, interface

I'm trying to navigate in Blender, but I can't pan around the scene.

Comment: do you mean pan (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panning_(camera))? What version of Blender are you using? What have you tried (UI, mouse/keyboard combinations)?

Comment: Yes, Sazerac, it's what I need to do... And don't find...

Comment: Which version of blender and keymap are you using? 2.8 has a different default keymap which changes some of the view navigation controls.

Comment: See https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/interface/keymap/industry_compatible.html and https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/navigate/navigation.html depending on your version.

Comment: Shift + Middle mouse to "pan"

Answer (score 1):

Hold <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>[image: MMB] MMB</kbd> and drag the mouse to pan Blender 2.8 Release Candidate.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Blender 2.8, you may be using the new [industry compatible keymap](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/interface/keymap/industry_compatible.html), in which case, you pan by holding <kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>[image: MMB] MMB</kbd> and dragging your mouse.

Otherwise you can use <kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>[image: MMB] MMB</kbd> with the [old default keymap](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/navigate/navigation.html#panning).